# "Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)"

Tags: perl, rpm

I use CentOS 6.5 for my server with below repository:

- IUS
- epel
- ces-standard-*
- base/upgrade/extras

When I tried to update today (it's been a while I haven't updated this server), I got the following errors:

```
---> Package perl-Clone.x86_64 0:0.31-3.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package perl-DBI.x86_64 0:1.616-1.of.el5 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8) for package: perl-DBI-1.616-1.of.el5.x86_64
---> Package perl-MLDBM.noarch 0:2.04-1.of.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8) for package: perl-MLDBM-2.04-1.of.el5.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(FreezeThaw) for package: perl-MLDBM-2.04-1.of.el5.noarch
---> Package perl-SQL-Statement.noarch 0:1.33-1.of.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Params::Util) >= 1.00 for package: perl-SQL-Statement-1.33-1.of.el5.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Params::Util) for package: perl-SQL-Statement-1.33-1.of.el5.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8) for package: perl-SQL-Statement-1.33-1.of.el5.noarch
---> Package perl-YAML.noarch 0:0.72-1.el5.rf will be installed
---> Package subversion-perl.x86_64 0:1.6.11-10.el6_5 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.3()(64bit) for package: git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.x86_64
---> Package perl-DBI.x86_64 0:1.616-1.of.el5 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8) for package: perl-DBI-1.616-1.of.el5.x86_64
---> Package perl-FreezeThaw.noarch 0:0.5001-1.of.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8) for package: perl-FreezeThaw-0.5001-1.of.el5.noarch
---> Package perl-MLDBM.noarch 0:2.04-1.of.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8) for package: perl-MLDBM-2.04-1.of.el5.noarch
---> Package perl-Params-Util.x86_64 0:1.07-1.of.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8) for package: perl-Params-Util-1.07-1.of.el5.x86_64
---> Package perl-SQL-Statement.noarch 0:1.33-1.of.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8) for package: perl-SQL-Statement-1.33-1.of.el5.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: perl-DBI-1.616-1.of.el5.x86_64 (ces-standard)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
Error: Package: perl-Params-Util-1.07-1.of.el5.x86_64 (ces-standard)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
Error: Package: perl-FreezeThaw-0.5001-1.of.el5.noarch (ces-standard-noarch)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
Error: Package: git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (ces-standard-deps)
           Requires: libcurl.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: perl-MLDBM-2.04-1.of.el5.noarch (ces-standard-noarch)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
Error: Package: perl-SQL-Statement-1.33-1.of.el5.noarch (ces-standard-noarch)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

*I use IOS repo to get PHP5.5 so I would understand getting conflicts on it but the error concerns PERL which I never used…*

Am I supposed to report this in repository mailing list? I could try `skip-boken` but I don't consider it as a good solution.

Comment: You messed up perl-5.8.8 for centos 6.5 and centos 5.0.Centos 6.5 repos didnt miss perl-5.8.8.Read your yum output result got el6 and el5.You created your own problem.

Comment: Read the link here :https://pkgs.org/download/perl%28:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8%29 . How did you mess up repos for el5 and el6 ?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this will help you or not but check out this linke:

https://serverfault.com/questions/401504/munin-on-centos-6-missing-perl-module-compat-5-8-8

It look to me like you have many perl rpms installed for el5 instead of el6 and this is probably why you are receiving these errors.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! (in fact, ces-standard was a centos5 only repo)

Comment: @GoinOff, You didnt answer it correctly.You didnt read the yum output properly. How KuroNeko messed up repos for el5 and el6 on yum.